# Gradle: produced WAR file has two versions of JAR from child project

Tags: eclipse, gradle, jar, jetty, war

I have a root project that builds WAR, and two child projects that build JARs. The root project references the child project in this way:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

jar.enabled = false
war {
    dependencies {
        runtime project(':application1')
        runtime project(':application2')
    }
}
```

application2 depends on application1:

```
dependencies {
    compile '...:application1:1.+'
}
```

The WAR file includes two versions of application1.jar: one from repository, another just built.

EDIT: Application2 has to depend on application1 as a JAR because that simplifies debugging in Eclipse with embedded Jetty: Eclipse automatically adds application1.jar to classpath of Jetty server launch configuration.

Comment: Why does application2 depend on application1 that way? It shouldn't.

Comment: How should dependency be specified?

Comment: `compile project(':application1')`.

Comment: >>Why does application2 depend on application1 that way?<< That configuration simplifies debugging in Eclipse with embedded Jetty.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified dependency on `application1` project differently for the root project and for the `application2`.

For your `application2` it was made as dependency on a library within some repository, but your root project depends on it as on a subproject. Gradle can't determine, that some library in the repo is the same, as subproject's artifact.

If you don't want to get 2 versions of the same lib, you have to make it dependent from the same library: either as

```
compile '...:application1:1.+'
```

or as

```
runtime project(':application1')
```

Anyway, it seems to be prefferable, to make it depending on the same subproject in both cases, rather then on some project and on the library in repo.

Comment: That does not help my use case. See my edit in the question.

Comment: @isobretatel then the only way is to declare one of dependencies as provided, have you tried it?

Comment: >> declare one of dependencies as provided<< - How?

Comment: Take a look here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html#N15B7E
WAR plugin provides 2 additioanl configurations: providedCompile and providedRuntime

Comment: I would have to duplicate reference to JAR: war {
    dependencies {
        runtime project(':application1')
        runtime project(':application2')

        providedCompile servlet
        providedCompile 'mycompany:application1:DEVELOP-1.+'
    }
}